Is delivery order of unary gRPC calls on a single RPC guaranteed?
We recently discovered a production issue that was caused by 2 unary RPC calls fired off in quick succession, on separate RPCs, often being received and processed out-of-order. We combined these 2 calls into a single RPC with a new discriminator field in the message to specify what the call should do. Experimentally, this has solved the issue 100%, however I can't find anything explicitly stating that unary RPC calls will be delivered in the order they are called (I'm ignoring the possibility of message failure for now and just thinking about the nominal case.)
I know converting to a streaming RPC would guarantee ordering, but that's a bit difficult in this particular instance for architectural reasons. If I can't guarantee the expected receipt order I'll probably just add a third value to the discriminator that tells the receiver to do thing one and then immediately do thing two so the RPC ordering doesn't come into play, but I'm still curious if this guarantee exists.
Both client and server are using the gRPC c++ asynchronous API with a single thread managing the completion queue, if that makes any difference.
Thank you

This most likely not even related to to gRPC calls at all, but "just" to multithreading. When in a multithreaded environment there is no absolute guarantee that things will be processed in exactly the order you called them (due to thread scheduling). In other words you have a race condition.

There is no guaranteed delivery order of separate RPCs. RPCs are independent, and can be routed to different servers. Even when the same server receives them, multiple things along the line could reorder them.
If you create RPCs serially, waiting for the previous one to complete before starting the next, then they clearly will have an ordering. You can also combine the operations into a single RPC or use a single streaming RPC.
